# MySql Autoincrement field does NOT use the next available value

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I defined an autoincrement ID field with 7 digits (`int(7) ZEROFILL`), so as to get 0000001, 0000002, 0000003, etc., enough for the table to contain as many as 10 000 000 rows.
At the beginning all was OK. Then I noticed that the field would "skip" entire ranges. For example, it would directly go from 0000100 to 0000200.
Things became very complicated when it went directly to 9999999, which is the last value allowed by `int(7)`, because the next time it set the "10000000" value, which contains 8 digits, whereas it had so far used only 0.005% of the values available with `int(7)`.

The problem is that I really need an 7-digit format for this field.

Is there a way to really force the field to use the next available value?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT : FYI the row definition is `int(7) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Can you show your table definition?

Comment: is the increment in id fixed or does it vary?

Comment: Note that INT(7) is not in fact a 7 digit field. The number in parentheses means something else entirely.

Comment: check auto increment variable SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';

Answer (score 1):

Using `AUTO_INCREMENT` should work. See this [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1388/1). Using `ZEROFILL`does not affect the data since it is only for data **representation**.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, that's not how AUTO_INCREMENT is supposed to work. It's basically a counter and, as such, it doesn't lookup the *next available value*. It simply increments the counter.

What does it mean in practice? You might have sequential values: 1, 2, 3... but as soon as you insert a larger value manually (e.g. `1000`) the counter will be incremented so next value is `1001`. Even if you remove rows, the counter will stay at `1001`. The only way to reset is to issue an ALTER TABLE stametement.

If that's not the desired behaviour, AUTO_INCREMENT is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: For example, why did the counter jump from 2000203 to 9999999, whereas I never deleted any rows in the meantime ? I guess a normal behaviour would have been setting the value 2000204.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that someone, not necessarily you, inserted such larger ID manually. Do you already have 2 million records?

Comment: There is no such risk ;-) At this stage, my website is still under development on my PC and is not accessible over internet yet.

Answer (score -1):

Use Max(Id) to get the max id before insert and then insert next record with **Max(Id)+1**